# Python-docx How to set space after paragraphs of the same style

Tags: python, python-docx

I have noticed when using python-docx that if I apply a style to to each paragraph in order, but have a style of `space_after = Pt(12)`, Word does not accept the space_after setting.  I've noticed in the Paragraph options that "Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style" is checked.  Is there any way to get around this so the `space_after` setting will be applied?

I've used a new line character at the end of my text, but I will not always want a new line.  Sometimes, I might want a partial line, or a specific size.

Comment: Can you improve your question with a [mcve]? E.g., provide some code that simply create a new doc, defines the paragraph styles, and insert 2 simple paragraphs.

Comment: My hope was that the creator of python-docx would see the question and be able to provide comment. If he doesn't show up in a day or so, I'll put together a minimal example as you request.  For those that have experience with python-docx, they'll understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: he's active on here, and I'm pretty sure he's going to ask for MCVE as well unless it is something super-obvious (perusing the documentation, that doesn't seem to be the case). I am familiar with his other package python-pptx but it is functionally very similar to python-docx, and I've got many years experience working with Word/PowerPoint/Excel automation with python, VBA, etc., so it's not that I don't understand what you're asking about, but rather "questions asking why this code doesn't work" should always include an MCVE in order to assist those who would help answer your question.

Comment: I'm talking about a feature of python-docx as it relates to a setting in MS Word rather than specific code. As I understand it now, there is no way to deselect the "Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style" when there should be otherwise, formatting in some instances becomes impossible.

Comment: You're talking about two features of MS Word, one of which is explicitly in docx (`space_after`) with the observation that this does not do what you think it should do, or that it's somehow not working as expected (interplay/dependencies with the other setting in Word). This might be implementation bug in docx package, or it may be some edge case that needs a workaround function or maybe you're just doing something wrong! Without seeing your code, it's not really possible (even for Steve) to say what the problem is.

Comment: it looks like this is probably overridden by a document template setting. you may need to remove the `<w:contextualSpacing/>` property of the paragraph(s).

Comment: I know it was 2 different features, one being in word and I know what the check box in MS Word does: It negates the effect of `space_after` in docx.  Your answer is awesome in that it is able to get rid of the attribute that checks the box I wanted unchecked.  If I could do more than just accept your answer, I would.

Comment: cheers! so this is what's meant by a "workaround" function in docx/pptx code. some things just aren't exposed via those libraries, yet or maybe ever. fortunately *most* things can still be handled via the underlying XML, provided you can identify the differences etc. some may be more involved/complicated than this but the idea is figure out how two XML parts differ, and then manipulate accordingly.

Comment: Sounds so simple and in thinking about it, it is simple, but actually doing it and comparing the XML files is likely more than most people want to do, but I love it.  Thank you so much!

Comment: that's what I thought at first, too :) but I've done a few now and they get easier each time. still haven't tackled anything really complex with lots of dependencies, but only because I haven't needed to. yet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've built a document with a few paragraphs of the same style ("Normal") and various `space_after`:

[image]

Select all paragraphs and toggle the "Dont' add space between paragraphs of the same style" to checked.

Now it looks like so:

[image]

Save and close the document from Word, then examine it via docx:

```
>>> from docx import Document
>>> document = Document(r'c:\debug\doc1.docx')
>>> for p in document.paragraphs:
...     print(p.paragraph_format.space_after)
...
635000
None
None
```

So, clearly the `space_after` is retained, but it's not being observed in the document as it's overridden by the checkbox option. This is given by the `<w:contextualSpacing/>` element of the `<w:pPr>` (I notice this by examining the `\word\document.xml` part of the Docx).

```xml
<w:p xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" w:rsidR="00E00961" w:rsidRDefault="00174F18">
  <w:pPr>   
    <w:spacing w:after="1000"/>   
    <w:contextualSpacing/> 
  </w:pPr>  
  <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/> 
  <w:r>   
    <w:t>hello, world!
    </w:t>  
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

You can remove these from the underlying XML like so:

```python
for p in document.paragraphs:
    p_element = p._element
    cspacing = p_element.xpath(r'w:pPr/w:contextualSpacing')[0]
    cspacing.getparent().remove(cspacing)
```

After removing those elements, open the document again and observe the toggle has been turned off, and the paragraphs observe the `space_after`:

[image]

Comment: Nice job David! :)

Comment: This is excellent!!!!  I think you'll help a lot of people with this answer because I've looked and the answers posted in the last 2 - 3 years that I've seen didn't really give any options, but this is clear, to the point, and looks like it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I tried David Zemens answer with an ordered list of style "List Number", but still had the check on "Dont't add space between paragraphs of the same style" in my docx file.

When examining the underlying xml files, I found a "w:contextualSpacing" entry in the "List Number" section of word/styles.xml.

My work-around is to rewrite the docx file (archive) without that contextualSpacing entry:

```
from io import BytesIO
import re
from zipfile import ZipFile

def remove_contextual_spacing_from_style(docx_path, style_name):
    mod_docx = BytesIO()
    style_byte = style_name.encode('utf-8')
    # load docx file as zip archive
    with ZipFile(docx_path, 'r') as old_docx, ZipFile(mod_docx, 'w') as new_docx:
        # iterate through underlying xml files
        for xml_item in old_docx.infolist():
            with old_docx.open(xml_item) as old_xml:
                content = old_xml.read()
                # search style_name section in word/styles.xml
                if xml_item.filename == 'word/styles.xml':
                    cspace = re.search(b'"%s".*?<\/w:pPr>'%(style_byte), content)
                    # remove contextualSpacing entry
                    if cspace:
                        cspace = cspace.group(0)
                        wo_cspace = cspace.replace(b'<w:contextualSpacing/>', b'')
                        content = re.sub(cspace, wo_cspace, content)
                # store xml file in modified docx archive
                new_docx.writestr(xml_item, content)
    # overwrite old docx file with modified docx
    with open(docx_path, 'wb') as new_docx:
        new_docx.write(mod_docx.getbuffer())

# example usage with style "List Number"
remove_contextual_spacing_from_style('path_to.docx', 'List Number')
```

Used sources:

under "Use case #3, attempt #3"
https://medium.com/dev-bits/ultimate-guide-for-working-with-i-o-streams-and-zip-archives-in-python-3-6f3cf96dca50

https://techoverflow.net/2020/11/11/how-to-modify-file-inside-a-zip-file-using-python/